# Flutter increase height of TextFormField

Tags: android, ios, flutter

I am creating a Flutter app. i made the design like this. 
[image]

My TextFormField form field for email and password heights are small. I want it to be the same size of the button.

```
final email = TextFormField(
    keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
    autofocus: false,
    initialValue: 'sathyabaman@gmail.com', 
    style: new TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.normal, color: Colors.white),
    decoration: InputDecoration(
      hintText: 'Email', 
      contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 10.0, 20.0, 10.0),
      border: OutlineInputBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(32.0)
      ),
    ),
  );
```

Whats the syntax for the height in text form field.

Comment: you can use `SizedBox` property for change the width and height

Comment: If you want to add multiple lines, use `maxLines: 5`

Answer (score 86, accepted):

Just adjust the contentPadding in InputDecoration.

[image]

```
final email = TextFormField(
    keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
    autofocus: false,
    initialValue: 'sathyabaman@gmail.com',
    style: new TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.normal, color: Colors.white),
    decoration: InputDecoration(
      hintText: 'Email',
      contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 25.0, horizontal: 10.0),
      border: OutlineInputBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(32.0)),
    ),
  );
```

Comment: I want to decrease its height to smaller than its default height but it doesn't work. Why?

Comment: How can we make content padding to be at center in inputtextform field?

Comment: @Sokheang Khun i use negative values to decrease the padding, but not sure if this is a practical way to do this

Comment: @SokheangKhun have you found any answer to this?

Comment: Yes, I follwed @Ajay Kumar's answer

Answer (score 31):

[image]

Use these two lines to control `TextFormField` Height inside `InputDecoration` .

```
isDense: true, 
contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 10, 10, 0),
```

Full example

```
Material(
                elevation: 4,
                shadowColor: Colors.blue,
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 12),
                  child: TextFormField(
                    controller: searchProvider.searchController,
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        hintText: 'hintText',
                        isDense: true, // important line
                        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 10, 10, 0),// control your hints text size
                        hintStyle: TextStyle(letterSpacing: 2, color: Colors.black54, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                        fillColor:  Colors.white30 ,
                        filled: true,
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30), borderSide: BorderSide.none)),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
```

Comment: Anybody knows what is `isDense` for

Comment: isDence is whether the [InputDecorator.child] is part of a dense form (i.e., uses less vertical space).   according to flutter documention

Answer (score 23):

You can change the height by changing the minLines value just try this

```
               TextFormField(
                           keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
                           controller: _opTextController,
                           decoration: InputDecoration(
                               isDense: true,
                             border: OutlineInputBorder(
                               borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.black)
                             )

                           ),
                           maxLines: 5,
                           minLines: 3,
                           // controller: cpfcontroller,
                         )
```

Comment: Your answer is unclear. Please provide a description for your code.

Comment: Hey @Momoro you can use this code if you don't want to pass a static height to your TextFormField if minLines is 1 and maxlines is 2  then a single line TextFormField  will be visible and its height will be increased dynamically while user writes more words in the field .Its height will be increased up to 2 lines because maxLines =2 if you initially want to show  a bigger TextFormField then increase minLines                                                                                                                       . if you are still not clear please let me know

Answer (score 12):

Set the `expands` attribute on `TextFormField` to be `true` then put `TextFormField` into a `SizedBox` with a `height`

```
SizedBox(
   height: 40.0,
   child: TextFormField(
    keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
    autofocus: false,
    expands: true, // Setting this attribute to true does the trick
    initialValue: 'sathyabaman@gmail.com', 
    style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.normal, color: Colors.white),
    decoration: InputDecoration(
      hintText: 'Email', 
      contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 10.0, 20.0, 10.0),
      border: OutlineInputBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(32.0)
      ),
    ),
  ),
)
```

Comment: It will work until you give it an error

Answer (score 6):

You can user this code to customized your TextFormField

```
new SizedBox(
  width: 200.0,
  height: 300.0,
  child: const Card(child: const Text('Hello World!')),
)
```

Comment: The `const Cart(...)` should be `new TextFormField(...)`, right?

Comment: You can replace `Card` child with your `TextFormField` instead of `Text('Hello World!')`. Shown in answer.

Comment: use double.infinity at width value to get dynamic width :)

Comment: It didnot work, Can we give height to text fields by another way?

Answer (score 5):

**Screenshot:**

[image]

---

**Code:**

You need to use a `SizedBox` and `TextField.maxLines` property.

```dart
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  final height = 100.0;
  return Scaffold(
    body: SizedBox( // <--- SizedBox
      height: height,
      child: TextField(
        cursorColor: Colors.red,
        maxLines: height ~/ 20,  // <--- maxLines
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          filled: true,
          hintText: 'Hint text',
          fillColor: Colors.grey,
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Answer (score 4):

There's another alternative to adding extra, permanent padding to cover the `errorText` — which would probably mess up many designer's original project.

You could create a modified version of the [source's `TextFormField`](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/text_form_field.dart).

To achieve just that, you can:

1. Copy-paste all of the content in the [source's `TextFormField`](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/text_form_field.dart).
2. Rename your custom `TextFormField` just so you avoid naming conflicts with the original.

   - You should probably also rename the internal state class.
   - In VS Code, you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> to replace `TextFormField` for, say, `TextFormFieldWithErrorTextOption`.
3. Add another parameter to the `TextFormField`'s constructor (below [this line](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/1ca4815035e6aa14831d8148062c732be3a458c4/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/text_form_field.dart#L175)), say, `errorTextPresent`:

   ```dart
   // `true` is the current implicit default, i.e., showing the `errorText`
   bool errorTextPresent = true
   ```
4. Change the [decoration's initialization](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/1ca4815035e6aa14831d8148062c732be3a458c4/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/text_form_field.dart#L220) for the internal `TextField`:

   1. From:

      ```dart
      decoration: effectiveDecoration.copyWith(field.errorText)
      ```
   2. To:

      ```dart
      decoration: effectiveDecoration.copyWith(
          errorText: errorTextPresent ? field.errorText : null)
      ```
5. Then, you can use your new `TextFormField` similarly to how you use any `TextFormField`:

   ```dart
   TextFormFieldWithErrorTextOption(
     errorTextPresent: false, // `false` will disable the `errorText`
     ...
   ),
   ```

Comment: I have also created a Flutter Issue for this. It's the [#52634](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/52634)

Comment: this solution worked great for me and I can now hide the error text, but unfortunately the borders are not colored red anymore when a validation error occurs. Is there a way to add that?

Answer (score 4):

If anyone's searching for a different solution to change its height, besides changing the Theme. You can use the decoration's constraints parameter:

```
decoration: const InputDecoration(
            constraints: BoxConstraints(maxHeight: 50, minHeight: 50),
            labelText: "Your Label")
```

Comment: This actually messes with your hint text. If you give less height then the hint text does not stay in center & disturbs the UI.

Answer (score 3):

just add a Container. Adjust the height of the Container as per Your requirement and make textformfield the child of the container.

Comment: This is the only way I found for **reducing** the default height. The question is about increasing the height. Anyway, to **reduce** the default size, you also have to consider validation errors and increase the height if validation returns error string. E.g.: `Container(height: validator == null ? 40 : 62, width: double.infinity,  child: TextFormField(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

Use a TextField or a TextFormField, add this parameters, `maxLines`. See code below:

```
final inputBorder =
        OutlineInputBorder(borderSide: Divider.createBorderSide(context));

    TextFormField(
                controller: _myController,
                keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  constraints: const BoxConstraints.expand(
                  height: 300, width: 400
                ),
                  hintText: 'What is Your Question?',
                  border: inputBorder,
                  focusedBorder: inputBorder,
                  enabledBorder: inputBorder,
                  filled: true,
                  contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                ),
                maxLength: 250,
                maxLines: 50,
    
              ),
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of different methods to do this. TextFormField does not have a height attribute, and the error handling and labels all inter-relate, which make behavior complicated depending on the behavior you prefer.

First, the basic way to do this is to have a parent set the size, and set your TextFormField to expand:

```
SizedBox(
 height: 50,
  child: TextFormField(
   expands: true,
   maxLines: null,
   minLines: null,
  ),
),
```

Caveats to this: You can't limit lines on the form to 1. This can be a problem if you want to list a high character count field, and you don't want it to wrap.

In that case, here is a solution to manually set the height using the Text to drive it:

```
TextFormField(
 decoration: InputDecoration(
  labelStyle: TextStyle(
   fontSize: 16,
  ),
 ),
 style: TextStyle(
  height: 2.5,
  textBaseline: TextBaseline.ideographic,
  overflow: TextOverFlow.ellipsis,
  fontSize: 12,
 ),
),
```

The height is a multiple of the font size.  This is still wonky, however it allows you to expand the height without affecting the label of the field (as long as you set a label fontSize, otherwise the label will be the same as the font size you set for the main style).

The label is a key consideration. If you try to set the height of the TextFormField using content padding (a common answer from other users), your label is affected by that padding, which isn't ideal for most cases.  This is the padding solution:

```
TextFormField(
 decoration: InputDecoration(
  contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 30.0),
 ),
)
```

But this solution would bump your labels down with the contents.  It does, however, work, and is a valid solution, just unacceptable in most cases.

Answer (score -1):

```
 Expanded(
                          child: TextFormField(
                            controller: emailAddressController,
                            obscureText: false,
                            decoration: InputDecoration(
                              labelText: 'Email Address',
                              labelStyle: TextStyle(
                                fontFamily: 'Lexend Deca',
                                color: Color(0xFF95A1AC),
                                fontSize: 14,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                              ),
                              hintText: ' Enter your email here ...',
                              hintStyle: TextStyle(
                                fontFamily: 'Lexend Deca ',
                                color: Color(0xFF95A1AC),
                                fontSize: 14,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                              ),
                              enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                borderSide: BorderSide(
                                  color: Color(0xFFDBE2E7),
                                  width: 2,
                                ),
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                              ),
                              focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                borderSide: BorderSide(
                                  color: Color(0xFFDBE2E7),
                                  width: 2,
                                ),
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                              ),
                              filled: true,
                              fillColor: Colors.white,
                              contentPadding:
                                  EdgeInsetsDirectional.fromSTEB(
                                      10, 10, 0, 10),
                            ),
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontFamily: ' Lexend Deca',
                              color: Color(0xFF2B343A),
                              fontSize: 14,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                            ),
                          ),
                        )
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SizedBox(
 height: 50,
  child: TextFormField(
   InputDecoration(
   isDense: false,
   filled: true,
    ) 
  ),
),
```

Comment: Although this code might answer the question, I recommend that you also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.