# How to style a form TextFormField when its in invalid state in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I have styled a TextFormField wrapped inside a SizedBox.  How can I style the field the same as its original style when it is in invalid state?

[image]

Here is the code of the Widget:

```
SizedBox(
                                  height: globals.StandardWidgetHeight,
                                  child: TextFormField(
                                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                                      border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                          borderRadius:
                                          BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5))),
                                      filled: true,
                                      fillColor: Colors.white,
                                      labelText: 'Name *',
                                    ),
                                    controller: _NameController,
                                    validator: (value) {
                                      if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                                        return 'Please enter Name';
                                      }
                                      return null;
                                    },
                                  ),
                                ),
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because of `SizedBox(height: ...)`. When validator message shows up, it will take a little space at bottom; but your current `TextFormField` has been fitted with the height `globals.StandardWidgetHeight` of `SizedBox`, so it would reduce height to have enough space to show validator message.

To change that, your can consider to remove the `SizedBox` outside `TextFormField` and replace it with different method to set height. Checkout: [Flutter increase height of TextFormField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50523006/flutter-increase-height-of-textformfield)

**EDIT:**

I was thinking that the problem you're mentioning is the height changing. If you want a deeper customize, such as `errorBorder` consider to read: [Flutter: TextFormField Validator breaks the style of field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61106178/flutter-textformfield-validator-breaks-the-style-of-field)

Comment: Thanks Nguyen, its working by adding these 2 lines: isDense: true, // important line
                        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 10, 10, 0),// control your hints text size